# Send an ARP request manually from Windows

Tags: command-line, arp, sniffer

I'm training myself on network scanning and i'm focusing on how to identify a sniffer on my net. 
Searching on the web, i find that a possible way is the ARP method: i must send an ARP request to a suspect no broadcast IP to check if it's in promiscuous mode.

My doubt is: if my pc is a Windows 7 machine, is there a way to send manually an ARP resuest? Possibly from command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use tools like nmap.

```
nmap -sP -PR <IP address/subnet>
```

For windows you can use the GUI version of nmap - zenmap.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this version of [arping](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/tree/master/Examples/Arping) for Windows. If you want an already compiled executable you can find it [Here](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/releases/download/v17.02/pcapplusplus-17.02-windows-mingw32-gcc-5.3.0.zip) (under the "examples" folder).

Usage:

`Arping.exe -i <IP_ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_INTERFACE> -T <TARGET_IP_ADDRESS>`

Answer (score 2):

another simple way:

- ping TARGET_IP_ADDRESS

then

- arp -a

the TARGET_IP_ADDRESS shall be shown as type `dynamic`.

Comment: This doesn't work on Windows 10. Another thread mentioned it works on Windows 7.